Llama 3.2 Vision-Instruct Inference Speed on A100 or H100 GPU
Can anyone provide an estimated time of how long does it take for Llama-3.2 Vision-Instruct 11-B model to:

process an image size of 1-MB and prompt size of 1000 words and
generate a response of 500 words

The GPUs used for inference could be A100, A6000, or H100.
